# Node.js Mongoose list all document by field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have simple app , its blog.

it's my schema in mongoose

```
 var blogSchema = new Schema({
  title:  String,
  author: String,
  body:   String
});
var Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);
```

i want show all blog post 
its my rout:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Blog.find(function (err, post) {
    res.render('default',{data: post});
  });
});
```

until now everything work fine , its show list of my post in json style.

when i want show just titles i change `{data: post}` to `{data: post.title}` its dont show anything.

Comment: The `post` argument of your callback function is an `array`. That's why `post.title` is `undefined`.

Comment: @rodrigo-medeiros do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Take a look at @freshnode answer. It solves your problem, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a collection of posts back from your Blog collection. That's fine - however, it sounds like what you are looking for is displaying a single item.

You'll either need to refer to it like this (which will return the title of the first post):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Blog.find(function (err, posts) {
    res.render('default',{data: posts[0].title});
  });
});
```

Or you'll need to create a new endpoint to get a single item:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Blog.find(function (err, posts) {
    res.render('default',{data: posts});
  });
});

app.get('/post/:postId', function(req, res, next) {
  Blog.findOne({_id: req.param('postId')}, function (err, post) {
    res.render('default',{data: post.title});
  });
});
```

The difference with the bottom one is I'm creating a named route that accepts a parameter called `postId`, which I then pass into the Mongoose method, and in turn the database tries to find a post with `_id` = `:postId`. So if I call:

`http://example.com/post/123` - the :postId parameter will be equal to `123`.

You access request parameters using the following syntax in Express:

`req.param('nameOfParam')`. In this example I used `req.param('postId')`. The `:` will automatically be stripped for you.

The second example also uses `findOne()`, which only retrieves you one row based on a set of criteria (in this case, find me one with an _id = :postId), rather than a collection.

**Edit:** to answer your question about getting the last ten posts, you can use the same code you had before, but with a little change:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Blog.find().limit(10).sort('id').exec(function (err, posts) {
    res.render('default',{data: posts});
  });
});
```

You can then render the titles in your view file. If you wanted `data` to just contain the post titles, you can do this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Blog.find().limit(10).sort('id').exec(function (err, posts) {

    var postTitles = posts.map(function(post) { return post.title; });
    res.render('default',{lastPostTitles: postTitles});

  });
});
```

[See the documentation on Mongoose Queries for more information](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: thanks, for one item 'findOne()' its work very well , but if want show last 10 post.title  because 'post ' is array post.title not gone work, do you have solution ? ( i just want show last 10 post blog in index page )